# Como validar o download de arquivos usando Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: testes, selenium-webdriver, testes-automatizados

Olá, escrevi um teste de automação no Webdriver Selenium usando C#, e uma das etapas requer baixar um arquivo XLSX do servidor.

Como posso validar se o arquivo foi baixado com sucesso e obter o nome dele?

Answer (score 0):

Há várias formas de validar se o arquivo está íntegro. 
Uma forma para validar é tirar o checksum [CRC32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) do arquivo ANTES e validar o arquivo que você baixou e comparar os valores.

No Linux, o comando é

```
cksum arquivo.txt
```

A saida será

```
linux@ubuntu:~$ cksum arquivo.txt
3474990042 214 arquivo.txt
```

Onde o primeiro código é o CRC32 do arquivo, o segundo é o número de bytes e o terceiro é o nome do arquivo.

Outra, que particularmente gosto mais, é usar o [MD5Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) do arquivo, da seguinte maneira:

```
linux@ubuntu:~$ md5sum arquivo.txt
```

e a resposta será

```
cbc8ccd6c7f5a111f494cfd4e0aea86e  arquivo.txt
```

onde a primeira coluna será o hash MD5 do arquivo e o segundo, o nome do próprio arquivo.

---

Comment: O arquivo que o selenium testa o download é dinâmico, e estou em ambientes Microsoft